# Resources should be closed issue is raised by sonar java even if the resource is closed

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I have two resources which are properly closed in finally clause with separate try catch blocks. But an issue is raised by sonar scanner to close the second stream even if it is closed.

Below is the sample snippet.

```
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("foo.in"));
            GZIPOutputStream gzos = null;
            try
                {
                    gzos = new GZIPOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        gzos.write(line.getBytes("UTF-8"));
                    }
                    gzos.flush();
                } catch (Exception exp) {

                } finally {
                    try {
                       if(reader != null) {
                        reader.close();
                       }
                    } catch (Exception exp) {}
                    try {
                       if(gzos != null) {
                        gzos.close();
                       }
                    } catch (Exception exp){}
                }
        } catch (Exception e){}
}
```

Is there any proper explanation for this rule?

Comment: perform the closing for every single flow, including for the outer-try

Comment: There is no apparent reason to use nested `try` blocks here. Why are you writing lines without line terminators?

Comment: But why the issue is raised only for GZIPOutputStream and not for BufferedReader?

Comment: Is it that way around? I would have expected an issue to be raised for BufferedReader but not GZipOutputStream.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException The issue should not be raised for both the streams. Because both of them are properly closed. That is the concern.

Comment: In this instance, both of them are properly closed. But what if you inserted a statement just before the second try block, and that statement threw an exception? Then `reader` would not be closed. You acquire the resources for `reader` outside of the inner try block, so you should also release them at the same level.

Comment: Just spotted out another use case. If a stream is declared outside first try block and is closed in finally block of that try block then there are no issues raised. But if any stream is declared with in inner try and closed in the finally block of inner try then the issues are raised.

Comment: Could be this 
https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-2185

Answer (score 2):

Your resource management seems ok to me - maybe Sonarqube complains because it can't follow your logic?

Anyhow - you'll probably be better off if you use a try-with-resources and forget about the close() nonsense :)

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try (  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("foo.in"));
           GZIPOutputStream gzos = new GZIPOutputStream(response.getOutputStream())  ) {
        String line; while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            gzos.write(line.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        }
        gzos.flush();
    }
}
```

Also, you usually don't want to flat-out ignore exceptions :)
I'm talking about the two empty `catch` around `gzos.write` - the ones inside the `finally` are actually ok (or at least, I would have written them too)

Comment: scratch the first sentence: the `BufferedReader` constructor cannot possibly throw an exception - editing

Comment: So why not just edit? Why the preview of coming attractions? Just a waste of time and soace.

Comment: Having a bad day? Try chocolate: it gives you dopamine and it's certainly better that being contentious with random dudes on the Internet :-)

Answer (score 0):

I scanned your code using SonarJava 5.0.1 plugin and `Sonar way` profile (includes the [Resources should be closed](https://sonarcloud.io/organizations/default/rules#rule_key=squid%3AS2095) rule). The issue was not found so you probably hit a false positive which already has been fixed.

[image: Issues found in file]